Assigning the owner variable outside of constructor or function
How is assigning a variable outside of a constructor or a function legit?
contract A {
    address public immutable OWNER = msg.sender;
}


Actually In Solidity, assigning an immutable variable outside of a constructor or function is a shortcut or legitimate for initializing a constant during contract creation.
Here's why it works:

immutable: This keyword makes the variable unchangeable after it's set.
Assignment outside of functions: Because it's immutable, the value
must be set during contract creation, and Solidity allows this
shortcut.

This is similar to setting the value in the constructor, but it's more concise.
contract A {
  address public immutable OWNER;

  constructor() public {
    OWNER = msg.sender;
  }
}

Both approaches achieve the same result: the OWNER variable is permanently assigned the address that deployed the contract.

Both of the answers are correct but both of them are AI generated.

This will still work even if I remove the immutable keyword.

yess @Ougi without immutable, the OWNER variable can be modified after contract deployment.

In Solidity, assigning a variable outside of a constructor or a function within a contract is entirely legitimate.
The example you provided demonstrates this with the OWNER variable being assigned outside any function or constructor.
In your example, OWNER is declared as a public immutable variable of type address. It is initialised with the value msg.sender, which represents the address of the account that deployed the contract. This assignment happens at the time of contract deployment and cannot be changed thereafter.

Both of the answers are correct but both of them are AI generated.
